# Meu codigo da esse erro Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém sabe porque da esse erro no `php` ao consultar uma tabela no `mysql`

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in 
>   /storage/emulated/0/site/loja/adm/editar_produto.php on line 85"

Sendo que em outra página usando o mesmo código funciona normal,o codigo está abaixo.Nessa mesma página busco informações para pode se editadas.

```
$sql ="Select * from categorias";
$resultado = $con ->real_query($sql);
$resultado= $con->use_result();
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
   echo $row["id"] ."$nbsp;";
   echo $row['nome'] ."&lt;br&gt;"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples, `$resultado= $con->use_result();` retornou **FALSE**, logo se `$resultado` tem **FALSE** como valor não é objeto e é impossível acessar `->fetch_assoc()`

Então bastaria tratar com uma `IF` e usar `$con->error` para pegar o erro da query, que é o que esta causando o retorno **FALSE** de `use_result`

Exemplo:

```
$resultado = $con->use_result();

if ($resultado) {
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
       echo $row["id"] ."$nbsp;";
       echo $row['nome'] ."&lt;br&gt;"; 
    }
} else {
    die($con->error);
}
```